# Is it accessible to make additional form inputs appear as the user selects options?

Tags: forms, input, accessibility, selection

Are there any accessibility issues with this:

User makes a selection, and additional options appear for sub-selection. For example:

**First state, before selection:**
[image]

**Second state: After user selects "Toyota Cars" from the list, more options appear**
[image]

**Third state: After user selects the cars they like, years appear for selection**
[image]

I could see how there could be a11y issues because the user can't tab through/listen to all the options before making a selection. But it's about narrowing down the selection. So in many ways it makes it MORE clear and accessible.

Please let me know of any issues or rules that may be being broken. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this as long as you respect proper labelling of your elements, make sure they are keyboard focusable and that the content is in the DOM. Here's is an example:

http://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/demos/feedback/feedback-en.html

If you change the first dropdown to "Critical issue..." you can see more options appear.

Since these appear AFTER the current focus point then it's perfectly acceptable to add form inputs.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the new options are not available to screen readers if they attempt to tab through the form before filling anything out.  The fact that you're adding elements to the DOM (or unhiding them) **after** the form control is good, but it's also helpful if you tell the screen reader that something was added.

You can have a visually hidden `<span>` or `<div>` that has `aria-live='polite'`.  When the user chooses 'Toyota Cars', you can update the hidden `<div>`.  So your html would have something like this:

```
<div id='moreStuff' aria-live='polite' class='visually-hidden'></div>
```

and your javascript would have something like this:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('moreStuff').innerText = 'Four Toyota brands have been added as options below.'
</script>
```